# do activiti modeler has the preview xml function?

Tags: activiti

Do Activiti modeler has the preview XML function?

I want to preview the Activiti's model XML content before saving it. I don't know if the Activiti modeler has this function or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking about the Eclipse modeler. The Activiti modeler does not allow preview in XML, but you can use the Camunda Modeler (which is largely compatible) which does have this feature.

Thanks,
Greg